# How to make the last part of this REGEX optional?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am looping through all the links on a page and matching their href values against the following pattern:

```
([^/]+)/([0-9]+)/([^/]+)
```

Problem is there are 2 types of link formats on the page:

```
1. /video/123/slug
2. /video/123
```

Number 1. gets captured fine with the above regex but the 2nd fails. I want to make the third piece of the regex (the slug) optional so that both link formats return true when matched agains the  regex. How to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the last bit in brackets of a non-capturing group and add a [`?`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html):

```
([^/]+)/([0-9]+)(?:/([^/]+))?
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `?` quantifier, which makes your pattern optional. It matches either 0 or 1 occurrence of the pattern.

Also, you need to group the last slash, with your last part of your regex, in a non-capturing group.

```
([^/]+)/([0-9]+)(?:/([^/]+))?
```

Comment: Hi, what does the `?:` do in this expression? Thanks.

Comment: @thomas. That is for non-capturing group.

Comment: so putting `?:` at the beginning of any set of `()` will make the result unavailable to referencing what it captures later on? Does that mean that it is unnecessary? Is that the standard way to do it when you know you won't be referencing it later? Thanks much.

Comment: @thomas. Yes exactly that. It won't be captured in any group.

Comment: so it's just a way to save memory, or what?

Answer (score 0):

If you add a `?` that should make the last part of the pattern optional.