# Regular Expression works as constructor, not as literal

Tags: javascript, regex

I was studying intro to regex stuff today and I came across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17432614/1252748) on SO

to test these patterns: `/video/123/slug` and `/video/123`, this regular expression was given:

`([^/]+)/([0-9]+)(?:/([^/]+))?`

I understand basically how it works, however, it only works when I put it in a constructor regex:

```
var test1 = new RegExp("([^/]+)/([0-9]+)(?:/([^/]+))?"),
a = "/video/123/slug",
b = "/video/123";
console.log(test1.test(a)); //true
```

but doing it literally fails:

```
/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)(?:/([^/]+))?")/.test(a) // all sorts of warnings and an error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
```

Why is this? http://jsbin.com/idegal/1/edit

Comment: Escaping of `/` is needed in the literal version! (Since you start and close the expression with that same character!)

Comment: Your `/`'s are not escaped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/` acts as a delimiter when you use regex literally..

So,you need to escape it `\/`.Your regex would be

```
  /([^\/]+)\/([0-9]+)(?:\/([^\/]+))?")/.test(a)
```

---

You don't need to escape it when used within string literal

Comment: Thanks very much. This seems to make regular expressions more complicated when they're literals. Are they frequently done that way? as a string, it seems like there's less to remember, and easier to read. Is this generally correct?

Comment: @thomas those are the [two](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp) syntax to create a regex object...So you can use any1 of it depending on your choice

Comment: @thomas: That depends on what you are searching for. Suppose you search for `'` and `"`, or `?:` etc.. You'd still need to escape those.     The constructor is especially useful to add changing (in a loop or depending on situation) variables into a regex. The literal however is usually treated as a fixed static object. So, both have their place/use and trade-offs.